# Jquery "on" when element is not initialized

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to add triger "on" when element don't exist?
For example I want to add "on" to button, so it would be like: (one global function for this class, so every button with class "task-details" will have onclick state when initialized)

```
$(".task-details").live('click', function(){/*do something*/});
```

But I want to do this event on popup which isn't exist on document ready, I made it dynamiclly, I think in older jquery .live('click',function()) whas doing it

Comment: Yes, read http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
$(document).on('click', ".task-details", function(){/*do something*/});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to bind to a container with a syntax like:

```
$('#containerId').on('click', '.task-details', function(e) {
    //event logic
});
```